# gitlab with non-bundled web-server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, gitlab

The fox icon is showed after installation.Only reconfigure external-link been suggested.

Followed [GitLab Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) of `using-a-non-bundled-web-server`

Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447552/1278112) to change some part of `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` 
Added `gitlab-apache24.conf` from `gitlab.com` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

After changed the domain name in conf, and reload apache2 get below error

```
systemctl status apache2.service
//folded some lines
apache2[25437]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/git/gitlab/public] does not exist
apache2[25437]: AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ecs1
apache2[25437]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
apache2[25437]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/httpd/logs/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab-apache24.conf:12
apache2[25437]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
apache2[25437]: Action 'configtest' failed.
apache2[25437]: The Apache error log may have more information.
systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

Actually,no `/home/git/gitlab/public` on the machine,either does `/var/log/httpd/logs/`.Is the problem from the `Apache2` in this machine?

Also changed `/etc/hosts`,add machine name after `127.0.0.1 localhosts`,but nothing changed.

The domain can be visited from other computers, and `ping` through the machine.But browser would show an `Apache` default page.

`apache` version 2.4,system `ubuntu 16.04 LTS`,`gitlab-ce` is install from `apt-install`

**UPDATE:**
  After `mkdir -p /var/log/httpd/logs/` `mkdir -p /home/git/gitlab/public` the status of `reload` turn to white from red.But the page showed on the domain is still the default page of Apache.

[Disabled default page](https://serverfault.com/a/345415) and it worked!

Comment: Your config is probably be broken. Did you try to create those directories? What does your gitlab-apache config actually look like?

Comment: Changed domain-name from [gitlab apache conf](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-apache24.conf).Would response other information in the main question.

Comment: Well if neither the log directories or document root exist you probably should change them to something that does or create the respective directories.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for help.Reload apache go on well.But the page show on external-link is still apache page.

Comment: Did you replace all FQDN lines? Did you disable the default page so it can bind to port 80?

Comment: I checked all FQDN lines are replaced.How to disable the default page?